# Trying to access a temporary array in another method

Tags: c#, arrays, temporary-objects

I'm sorry if this is a silly question, but as a beginner in coding, I find it hard to remember the limits/bounds of variables that I create. I am trying to create a temporary array in the `GetLetters()` method below, but I later need to access this information in the `EstimateGrade()` method so as to "*estimate a grade*" for the user based on their name.

I get the error that **"the name 'threeLetters' does not exist in the current context'**.

Is there a way to access the threeLetters array without creating a public array.

```
public int[] GetLetters(String userName)
    {
        //Creating an array that will hold the 3 values that determine grade
        int[] threeLetters = new int[3];

        char firstLetter = userName[0];
        threeLetters[0] = userName[0];
        char thirdLetter = userName[2];
        threeLetters[1] = userName[2];
        char fifthLetter = userName[4];
        threeLetters[2] = userName[4];

        if(userName.Length > 5)
        {
            threeLetters = new int[0];
        }

        return threeLetters;
    }

    public int EstimateGrade(int[] grade)
    {
        int sum = (threeLetters[0] + threeLetters[1] + threeLetters[2]) * 85;
        int result = sum % 101;
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Yes. If you look at the EstimateGrade method, the parameter you provided isn't being used in the method and the one being used is 'threeLetters' which cannot be accessed as it wasn't declared here. If you declare it in the parameter, you will be able to use it. Please remember that when you are using the EstimateGrade method and want to get the names from 'GetLetters' then you have to pass the return value of 'GetLetters' method into your EstimateGrade method. e.g. EstimateGrade(GetLetters(username)); I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @GrantWinney Thanks :)

Comment: @SorrelVesper Yes, this made sense and helped a lot! You actually answered a second question I had too haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`threeLetters[]` is local to `GetLetters()`, ie `threeLetters[]` is not accessible outside the `GetLetters()`. Since you are passing `threeLetters[]` as parameter to `EstimateGrade()` with alias name `grade[]` then change the threeLetters to grade. See the below code.

```
public int EstimateGrade(int[] grade)
{
    int sum = (grade[0] + grade[1] + grade[2]) * 85;
    int result = sum % 101;
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In most cases you can deduce the scope of any member by the `{}` braces. As far as classes are concerned the access modifiers add another layer to this.

So in your example all the variables are local to the methods, but not only them, everything inside `{}`:

```
public int[] GetLetters(String userName)
{    
    int[] threeLetters = new int[3];

    char firstLetter = userName[0];    
    char thirdLetter = userName[2];
    char fifthLetter = userName[4];

    if(userName.Length > 5)
    {
        threeLetters = new int[0];
    }

    return threeLetters;
}
```

In rare cases you may need variables with the same names for different cases so you can add more blocks that separate members where each nested block can access members of its parent block:

```
public int[] GetLetters(String userName)
{    
    int[] threeLetters = new int[3];

    // some special block 1
    {
        char firstLetter = userName1[0];    
        threeLetters[0] = firstLetter;
    }

    // some special block 2
    {
        char firstLetter = userName2[0];  
        threeLetters[1] = firstLetter ;             
    }

    if(userName.Length > 5)
    {
        threeLetters = new int[0];
    }

    return threeLetters;
}
```

Inside a class by default all members are private and local to the class:

```
class A
{
    // private by default 
    static string Foo()
    {
        return "This is class A";
    }
}

class B
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        var name = A.Foo(); // error, cannot access, A.Foo must be public
    }
}
```

If you want to access those variables from another method, you would need to define `threeLetters` as a field of your class (or move it the parent/class scope):

```
class A
{
    int[] threeLetters = new int[3];
}
```

The same applies to nested classes, each nested class can access members of its parent class:

```
class A
{
    static string Foo() { return "Class A"; }

    public class B
    {
        public static string Foo() { return A.Foo(); } // no error
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(B.Foo());
```